# How to put C++ dll running in Worker Thread under C# Window Form application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, multithreading, dll

I like to run C++ dll under worker thread so that C# application's windows form (those buttons on the form) is still usable. Now is once dll is running, buttons on windows form in C# application can't be clicked.

I have C++ class with member functions exported.

```
class Soln {
public:
      //Export functions
      Soln();
      ~Soln();
       voidgetObjectInformation(void);
       void setProcessOver(void);
};

/************These export funcitons are created*********/
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) Soln* Soln_Create() {
        return new Soln();
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void Soln_getObjectInformation(Soln* bsn) {
        return bsn->getObjectInformation();
    }
    __declspec(dllexport) void Soln_setProcessOver(Soln* bsn) {
        bsn->setProcessOver();
        return;
    }
    __declspec(dllexport) void Soln_delSoln(Soln* bsn) {
        bsn->~Soln();
        return;
    }
}
```

In C#, it is interfaced using `PInvoke`.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("Soln_Cpp_Dll.dll", EntryPoint = "Soln_Create")]
        public static extern IntPtr Soln_Create();

        [DllImport("Soln_Cpp_Dll.dll", EntryPoint = "Soln_delSoln")]
        public static extern void Soln_delSoln(IntPtr bsn);

        [DllImport("Soln_Cpp_Dll.dll", EntryPoint = "Soln_getObjectInformation")]
        public static extern IntPtr Soln_getObjectInformation(IntPtr bsn);

        [DllImport("Soln_Cpp_Dll.dll", EntryPoint = "Soln_setProcessOver")]
        public static extern void Soln_setProcessOver(IntPtr bsn);

        //Variables
        IntPtr Soln;

        public Form1()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Soln = Soln_Create();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Soln_delBaggageSoln(Soln);
        }

     }
```

Now the problem is once the dll is running, I can't click button4 to stop.

I searched and found that I can make a worker thread in C#.

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(oAlpha.Beta));
```

But it is just to create a new object, since I am expecting a return `IntPtr Soln`, how can I run the dll under worker thread?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest looking in to C++/CLI to make your C# to C++ interface much easier. You can write a managed wrapper class around your native C++ class for example, and use it as a regular class from C#. As for your example code, this is not a reproducible sample and it does not illustrate the problem. I don't see any places where threads are being created so it's impossible to know why a thread isn't stopping. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better see what is happening.

Comment: There are some functions they use mutex in c++ dll. CLR doesn't accept them and can't include header file inside CLR project. So I need to hide those mutex to CLR project. How can I do that? The way I implemented does not need to see those header files and C# project can compile.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of the C++ dll, or is it a third party component and all you have is the header with the class and C extern exports? Even if all you have is the class definition, you should still be able to make a C++/CLI project that links with the class header and dll so you'll have a nice managed wrapper class. Do you have any code samples in C++ of how to use that third party dll, or any documentation to use?

Answer (score -1):

To solve your problem, fire a task in c# when the button is clicked and forget it.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Soln_delBaggageSoln(Soln)); //for example
```

This way your UI thread is not blocked when the dll function is running as it would be running in a different thread.